# Java App Engine Datastore: How to query fields of object's inherited classes?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore

AppEngine 1.2.2. I define a class Product like so:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, table="Products")
public class Product {

 public Product(String title) {
  super();
  this.title = title;
 }

 public String getTitle() {
  return title;
 }

 @Persistent
 String title;

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key id;
}
```

I define a derived class Book like so:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, table="Products")
public class Book extends Product {

 public Book(String author, String title) {
  super(title);
  this.author = author;
 }

 public String getAuthor() {
  return author;
 }

 @Persistent
 String author;
}
```

I then make a new object like so:

PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
 pm.makePersistent(new Book("George Orwell", "1984"));

I can query for this new object using a query like:

Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + Book.class.getName() + " where author == param");
 query.declareParameters("String param");
 List results = (List) query.execute("George Orwell");

This returns the object, because I am querying a field 'author' defined on Book.

However this doesn't work:

Query query = pm.newQuery("select from " + Book.class.getName() + " where title == param");
 query.declareParameters("String param");
 List results = (List) query.execute("1984");

It throws an exception which states there is no field 'title', even through this is defined on the derived class Product.

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Field "title" does not exist in com.example.Book or is not persistent
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.store.exceptions.NoSuchPersistentFieldException: Field "title" does not exist in com.example.Book or is not persistent
```

It seems as if fields from inherited classes are not available in the Datastore queries.

Is this in fact possible with a variation on the syntax, or with annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjdo.html

Unsupported Features of JDO

The following features of the JDO interface are not supported by the App Engine implementation:

Unowned relationships. You can implement unowned relationships using explicit Key values. JDO's syntax for unowned relationships may be supported in a future release.
Owned many-to-many relationships.

"Join" queries. You cannot use a field of a child entity in a filter when performing a query on the parent kind. Note that you can test the parent's relationship field directly in query using a key.

JDOQL grouping and other aggregate queries.

Polymorphic queries. You cannot perform a query of a class to get instances of a subclass. Each class is represented by a separate entity kind in the datastore.

IdentityType.DATASTORE for the @PersistenceCapable annotation. Only IdentityType.APPLICATION is supported.

**There is currently a bug preventing preventing persistent fields on superclasses from being saved to the datastore. This will be fixed in a future release.**

Answer (score 1):

That query, using DataNucleus with any of the other datastores we support (e.g RDBMS, XML, Excel, etc), should indeed allow fields in superclasses; the query is valid JDOQL. If they don't work in GAE/J then report the issue in Google's issue tracker, though there is certainly an issue there about inheritance already
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/list